# how to insert tab limited text file into sql database using python?

Tags: python, sql, text-files

```
with open('employee.txt') as textfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(textfile, delimiter='\t')
    csvdata = []
    for row in csvreader:
        csvdata.append(row)

conn = pymysql.connect (host = "localhost",user = "root", passwd = "password",db = "details1")
c = conn.cursor()
for row in csvdata:
    c.execute("INSERT INTO employee6(serial_no, first_name, last_name, age, sex,city) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s','%s')" % (serial_no,first_name,last_name,age,sex,city))

conn.commit()
c.close()`enter code here`
```

but I am getting an error
 in ()
      8 c = conn.cursor()
      9 for row in csvdata:
---> 10     c.execute("INSERT INTO employee6(serial_no, first_name, last_name, age, sex,city) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s','%s')" % (serial_no,first_name,last_name,age,sex,city))
     11 
     12 conn.commit() 
NameError: name 'serial_no' is not defined
why am i getting this error

Comment: it seems that serial_no does not exist in your code. Did you define it?

Comment: I have serial_no in table i created and even in my text file

Comment: `print(row)` please

Comment: its printing my text file with extra white spaces

Comment: @cherry please show us at least one or two rows of the output of `print(row)` if possible. ANd that would the the `row`abouve your `c.execute()` line. That's kind of relevant for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
        c.execute("INSERT INTO employee6(serial_no, first_name, last_name, age, sex,city) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s','%s')" % (row["serial_no"], row["first_name"], row["last_name"], row["age"],row["sex"],row["city"]))
```

**Edited**

```
    with open('employee.txt') as textfile:
        csvreader = csv.reader(textfile, delimiter='\t')
        csvdata = []
        conn = pymysql.connect (host = "localhost",user = "root", passwd = "password",db = "details1")
        c = conn.cursor()
        for row in csvreader:
            c.execute("INSERT INTO employee6(serial_no, first_name, last_name, age, sex,city) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s','%s')" % (row["serial_no"], row["first_name"], row["last_name"], row["age"],row["sex"],row["city"]))


        conn.commit()
        c.close()
```

Comment: its throwing me an error saying" list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Comment: No, sorry, but no, it should **not** be that :) You are proposing the use of string interpolation, which not only makes the code vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), but also will break if, for example, the `serial_no` is a numeric data type in the DB where the above would attempt to insert a string.

Comment: Show output of `print(rows)` please @cherry

Comment: Above code is to make sure that we are inputting correct value in DB @shmee

Comment: ['Serial_no', 'FIRST_NAME', 'LAST_NAME', 'AGE', 'SEX', 'city', '']
['1', '', 'john', '', 'mathew', '', '32', 'm', 'bombay']
['2', '', 'jim', '', 'parker', '', '35', 'm', 'pune']
['3', '', 'sophia', '', 'ran', '', '28', 'f', 'kolkata']
['4', '', 'wendi', '', 'blake', '', '40', 'f', 'chennai'] @upasana

Comment: when I avoided " " for serial no, first_name its again throwing me an error serial_no not defined@shmee

Comment: okay. and that is because you have appended lists in csv data. Understood. Updating the answer but you may want to change the way of reading file because this is not an efficient way.

Comment: @cherry Try this and let me know if it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that reading the input file works correctly, you will have a list of list in your `csvdata` variable.

The way you try to create your SQL query string by using string interpolation is not recommended and potentially dangerous. It allows for [SQL injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), but also can make formatting the string to enforce the correct data types, especially for INSERT queries a pain.

All [DB-API 2](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/)-compliant adaptors alow to pass a [sequence of parameters](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/cursors.html#pymysql.cursors.Cursor.execute) along with your query string that the adaptor will safely replace.

Since `row` should already be a list when you iterate over `csvdata`, your `execute` call would look like this:

```
for row in csvdata:
    c.execute("INSERT INTO employee6(serial_no, first_name, last_name, age, sex,city) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s,%s)", row)
```

However, since your `csvdata` is already a list of lists, you could also use [executemany](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/cursors.html#pymysql.cursors.Cursor.executemany) instead of the above:

```
c.executemany("INSERT INTO employee6(serial_no, first_name, last_name, age, sex,city) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s,%s)", csvdata[1:])
```

Note: the `csvdata[1:]` is to exclude the header line from the INSERT.

Comment: its showing "not all arguments converted during string formatting"@shmee

Comment: Is there any row in your input file where any of the fields is missing or where there is an additional field? Which option did you use? The `execute()` or `executemany()`? If the `execute()`, print `row` before the insert to identify the potentially offending row.

Comment: I dont have any fields missing and i used execute many and print(row) before for loop and insert statement

Comment: `print(csvdata[:-1]` what does that return?

Comment: [['Serial_no', 'FIRST_NAME', 'LAST_NAME', 'AGE', 'SEX', 'city', ''], ['1', '', 'john', '', 'mathew', '', '32', 'm', 'bombay'], ['2', '', 'jim', '', 'parker', '', '35', 'm', 'pune'], ['3', '', 'sophia', '', 'ran', '', '28', 'f', 'kolkata'], ['4', '', 'wendi', '', 'blake', '', '40', 'f', 'chennai']] and its repeating@shmee

Comment: @cherry Wait, what? the last element of your `csvdata` is the complete document? Can you please update the question and show us what your code looks like right now?